# Using a Nullable<int> Foreign Key in a MS SQL Database Table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nullable

I have two tables, for simplicity lets pretend they're defined like this

```
Stack 
{
    ID       int  Primary Key
    Name     varchar(255), not null
}

User
{
    ID           int  Primary Key
    Name         varchar(255), not null
    Stack_ID     int, Foreign Key to Stack.ID nulls are allowed
}
```

My stored procedure for inserting a User looks something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_insertUser
    @id int,
    @name varchar(255),
    @stackID int
AS
    INSERT INTO User (ID, Name, Stack_ID) VALUES (@id, @name, @stackID)
GO
```

In my Model layer my user class I use a nullable to hold StackID

```
public class User
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     int? Stack_ID {get; set;}
}
```

My Data Access Layer I thought was pretty standard, but i'm having trouble, my InsertUser method looks something similar to this

```
 public void InsertUser(User entity)
 {
     ...
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
     {
         command.Connection = conn;
         command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         command.CommandText = "usp_insertUser";

         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", entity.ID);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", entity.Name);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stackID", entity.Stack_ID);
         conn.Open();
         ...
         //real stored proc returns the id of the item inserted so i use a reader
         SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         ....
    }
 }
```

My problem here, when I leave User.Stack_ID null, it doesn't insert a null in the database, instead I get an error, saying that @stackID was expected but wasn't there.  Why can't I just straight up insert this nullable int into the database?

Also, is there some one line way I could read this possible null int from the database?

When I did this I assumed this would work.

```
User.Stack_ID = (int?)reader["Stack_ID"];
```

that obviously doesn't work, and I have to do something sloppy like

```
try {
   User.StackID = (int)reader["Stack_ID"];
}
catch {
   User.StackID = null;
}
```

any help would be appreciated with working with these Nullable type.  Sorry for the noob questions, in the past when I had ints and wanted a null value or w/e I would set them to -1 or 0 or something, that doesn't work when they're foreign keys :-(

Comment: A primary key cannot be nullable in SQL Server.

Comment: I know that, but can a Foreign Key be nullable to a Primary Key..which would represent.."it doesn't have one of these objects"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stackID", entity.Stack_ID ?? (object) DBNull.Value);
```

To read a null value, you could do this:

```
User.StackID = reader.Field<int?>("Stack_ID");
```

This uses the [`Field` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx).  From MSDN:

> The Field method provides support for accessing columns as nullable types. If the underlying value in the DataSet is [DBNull.]Value, the returned nullable type will have a value of null.

Comment: In your top example I get Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'.  If I cast DBNull.Value to (object) the error goes away.  Is it correct to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special type called `DBNull` for inserting nulls into the database.

Try

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stackID", entity.Stack_ID.HasValue ? entity.StackId : DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `as`.

```
int? myNullableInt = reader["Stack_ID"] as int?;
```

The caveat to this is that if `reader["Stack_ID"]` is of a different datatype (eg string, decimal, etc.), then you will get null instead of an exception.

EDIT:
As for inserting into the database, if you insert with `command.Parameters.Add`, you do not need to change the datatype, it will support nullable values.